# Question about 'A convergence sequence of real numbers is bounded.'

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

The textbook proves this theorem as following (I am writing shortly rather than the exact words):

> Let $\lim (x_n)=x$ and $\epsilon:=1$, then there exists $K=K(1)$...
> (rest of the definition). Then,
>
> $$|x_n|=|x_n-x+x|\le|x_n-x|+|x|\lt1+|x|$$
>
> Let $M:= \sup \{|x_1|,|x_2|, ... , |x_{K-1}|,1+|x|\}$

And the proof follows.

I understand most of the proof, just have trouble understanding, why up-to $x_{K-1}$ ?

My main question is, is the following proof valid? If not, why?

> Given sequence is convergent. So, using the usual notations from the
> definition, the sequence $X=(x_n)$ has a limit $x$, therefore by
> definition and triangle inequality $|x_n|-|x|\le|x_n-x|<\epsilon$.
> Which implies, $|x_n|<M, \forall n\in\Bbb{N}$ by letting
> $M:=\epsilon+|x|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not valid, since you only have

$$|x_n|-|x|\le|x_n-x|<\epsilon$$

for all $n\ge N$, for **some** natural number $N = N(\epsilon)$. So

$$|x_n| \le |x|+\epsilon$$

might not be satisfied by $x_1, \cdots, x_{N-1}$.

Comment: Understood. Then the question arises, how do I know I have to set $\epsilon:=1$ ? It seems to me, it is trial and error method.

Comment: You don't have to choose $\epsilon=1$, you can use $\epsilon=1/2$ or even $100$.... but for different $\epsilon$, that would give you different $N(\epsilon)$ (which, again, it doesn't matter, since the set $\{1, \cdots, N(\epsilon)\}$ is finite anyway) @Kawrno

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Now please tell me this, why do I have to take the supremum or least upper bound of the set? Because the definition doesn't require that. The supremum is for sure the upper bound, but I don't need the least. So any value in $\Bbb{R}$ which is greater than each member of the set, can be considered as $M$ in my logic. And as the said set is finite, but $\Bbb{R}$ is infinite, such larger quantity is assured.

Comment: Again, you don't have to. But think it this way, if the book tell you that one can choose $M = \sup\{x_1, \cdots, x_{K-1}\}+1$ (which works), it is equally confusing: why is there a $1$ there? @Kawrno

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is valid only for $n$ sufficiently large.  To complete the proof, you have only to observe that the first $n$ elements of the sequence are necessarily bounded, because there are only finitely many of them.

Comment: If a sequence is bounded, it is necessary that all elements are bounded. Why just observe the first few $n$ elements?